# OpenLayers.js which files to use?

Tags: javascript, file, maps, openlayers, include-path

As i red from the `readme` file, `openlayers.js` has multiple choices for including files and themes.

What i would like is to use the `lightest solution of openlayers.js` files.

I included the `openlayers.light.js` in my app, and it creates maps but do not show them, check this:

[image]

do i forgot to include some other file?

my structure structure is this:

```
/vendor
   /js
     openlayers.light.js
     /img
     /theme
```

how to show maps layers?

Also does the `openlayers.light.js` will work on mobile devices (once fixed this problem :P )? or i'll need to include `openlayers.mobile.js` too?

This is the code not working with openlayers.light.js but working with openlayers.js (740kb) :

```
var _element = "#map";
 var map = new OpenLayers.Map (_element, {
    controls: [
    new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation({
      dragPanOptions: {
        enableKinetic: true
      }
    }),
    new OpenLayers.Control.Zoom()
    ],
    projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"),
    displayProjection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326")
  });

  var lonLat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(_lon, _lat).transform (
new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), // transform from WGS 1984
new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913") // to Spherical Mercator Projection
// map.getProjectionObject() doesn't work for unknown reason
);
  var markers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers( "Markers" );
  map.addLayer(markers);

  var size = new OpenLayers.Size(21,25);
  var offset = new OpenLayers.Pixel(-(size.w/2), -size.h);
  var icon = new OpenLayers.Icon(_img_map_marker, size, offset);
  markers.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(lonLat, icon.clone()));

  var mapnik = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM("Test");
  map.addLayer(mapnik);

  map.setCenter (lonLat,3);
```

**PS: my openlayers map js init method is ok, it works using the huge `openlayers.js (740KB)`, but not working with openlayers.light.js as i showed above**

html

```
<div id="map"></div>
```

css

```
img{max-width:none;}
#map{
width:300px;
height:300px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want to use mobile properties with openlayers as panning or zooming with hand you have to use openlayers.mobile.js.

you can use openlayers.light.js with mobile devices but not mobile functions.

i think your structure should be :

```
myProject
   /js
      openlayers.light.js
   /img
   /theme
```

and i have tried openlayers.light.js in http://jsfiddle.net/aragon/ZecJj/ and there is no problem with it.

My code:

```
var map = new OpenLayers.Map({
    div: "map",
    minResolution: "auto",
    maxResolution: "auto",
});

var osm = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM();
var toMercator = OpenLayers.Projection.transforms['EPSG:4326']['EPSG:3857'];
var center = toMercator({x:-0.05,y:51.5});
map.addLayers([osm]);


map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(center.x,center.y), 13);
```

and try to read [Deploying (Shipping OpenLayers in your Application)](http://docs.openlayers.org/library/deploying.html).

> OpenLayers comes with pre-configured examples out of the box: simply
>   download a release of OpenLayers, and you get a full set of easy to
>   use examples. However, these examples are designed to be used for
>   development. When you’re ready to deploy your application, you want a
>   highly optimized OpenLayers distribution, to limit bandwidth and
>   loading time.

you can change src file with this link and can see it still works.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://openlayers.org/dev/OpenLayers.light.debug.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://view.softwareborsen.dk/Softwareborsen/Vis%20Stedet/trunk/lib/OpenLayers/2.12/OpenLayers.light.js?content-type=text%2Fplain"></script>
```

i hope it helps you...

Comment: check my question pls i updated with my code, also i can't change js files structure, it's a standard for me all inside /vendor not on main root

Comment: i have updated [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aragon/ZecJj/) with your codes only one problem is that `dragPanOptions`. i think OpenLayers.light.js is not so detailed for special functions.

Comment: thank you man, you should bring me example for mobile and not , i need to use mobile too, and your code is really good, but so far from mine @Aragon

Comment: then i'll try your code with my folder structure and tell you about ;)

Comment: can you show me more like code i'm using right now? why do i need to change my code which it  works ?